# Angular JS 1.2 - animating child elements with ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

Dearest stackoverflowers,

I'm new to Angular JS and have read some [stuff](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) on how to animate the Angular way, still I'm very much confused on how to correctly implement it and what classes get added when and where. I feel like I had much more control over my animations with traditional jQuery (adding and removing classes). But maybe this is just because I'm used to it that way.

On pageload I want certain elements to animate in. So in my controller, on pageload, a variable (pageLoaded) gets set to true. And my surrounding content-wrapping div will have ng-show="pageLoaded".

This way I have successfully added an animation on the entire page using following CSS transitions/animations:

```
.page.ng-hide-add, .page.ng-hide-remove {
    display:block!important;
}

.popup.ng-hide-add  {
    -webkit-animation: 450ms bounceInRight reverse;
}

.popup.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-animation: 750ms bounceInRight;
}
```

But once I try to address child elements, the animations fail.

```
.page.ng-hide-add .child, .page.ng-hide-remove .child {
    display:block!important;
}

.popup.ng-hide-add .child {
    -webkit-animation: 450ms bounceInRight reverse;
}

.popup.ng-hide-remove .child {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-animation: 750ms bounceInRight;
}
```

Is this not supported by Angular? Or am I doing something wrong?

And if I understand correctly, no matter if you're using ng-hide, or ng-show..
the ng-hide classes should be used? Where they follow following logic:

- ng-hide-remove/ng-hide-remove-active show the element
- ng-hide-add/ng-hide-add-active hide the element

Can someone explain the difference between the regular and the active classes? How should they be used?

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: have you tried .child.ng-hide-remove and .child.ng-hide-add instead of just having .child?

Comment: Yes I have, didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Angular scans the document for things to animate, I have found that when wanting to animate a child element. You have to set a transition on the parent for as long as you want the children to transition.

For example.

```
.page.ng-hide-add, .page.ng-hide-remove {
   -webkit-transition: 1000ms;
}

.page.ng-hide-add .child, .page.ng-hide-remove .child {
    display:block!important;
}

.popup.ng-hide-add .child h1 {
    -webkit-animation: 450ms bounceInRight;
}

.popup.ng-hide-add .child h2 {
    -webkit-animation: 750ms bounceInRight 250ms;
}
```

**Angular will only add the 'animation' classes, if the HTML element with the NG-IF/NG-SHOW or ng-whatever element has a transition in the CSS specified for it.**